# Setting object property to the result of a sort without sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects, each with a property called `sort_order` that I need to change based on another property `score` but the catch is I can't actually change the order of the array which means no `Array.sort()`.

Basically I want this:

```
var scores = [{id:int, name:string, score:int, sort_order:int}, ...]; 
function compare(a,b){
    return b.score - a.score;
}
scores.sort(compare);
```

but instead of actually sorting I want to set `a.sort_order` and `b.sort_order` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sort order on them by sorting a different array. The simplest solution would be to sort a copy of the array:

```
scores.slice().sort(compare).forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.sort_order = i;
});
```

Comment: needs to apply the sort order to the original. An additional loop inside of the forEach could take care of it, but then we're talking a large amount of loops which I'd like to avoid for performance reasons

Comment: What do you mean? That `forEach` *is* just the loop that applies the order to the original objects. Nothing else needed.

Comment: wouldn't the `slice` function create the copy, which would then be used with the `forEach`

Comment: Yes, the `forEach` is iterating the copied *array*, but that array still contains the *original objects*. `slice` does not deep-copy the objects.

Comment: Ahhh... good call, didn't think about the fact that it was shallow copy. Thanks man! You saved me from a whole lot of sort algorithms.